# Crystal Reports Details Section

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Crystal Reports details section 
I need to bring some records from left to right and in the same report some records from top to bottom like this
               Math      Phy     History 
Ahmad     60       65         70 
Qudrat      45       70         80 
Hafiz            60      60         60

Names from top to bottom 
Subject and marks from left to right
Can someone please guide me how to do this?
I’m using SQL server store procedures

Answer (score 0):

Please look into using a CrossTab. The menu option is Insert, CrossTab...

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross tab control in crystal report. you need a proper data and given to cross tab. You must get the column and row value in stored procedure and in crystal report assign database column in crosstab report, data automatically bind and display as you require.

Please refer this links

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its